# RewriteRule to capture specific url and allow a substring of the same url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rule that works for this url:

/cobrand/partner;jsessionid=YIMle3Ap0AKEp?code=SOMEPARTNERCODE

```
RewriteRule ^/shop/partner /cobrand/partner [QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/shop/Partner(.*) /cobrand/partner$1 [QSA,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)code=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?cobrand/partner(.*)$ /store/affiliate/cobrand/redirect/code/%1? [R=301,L]
```

What I would like is to have a rule that will allow this url to be parsed as is whilst allowing the above to also match:

cobrand/partner?code=SOMEPARTNERCODE&init=true

Also I have a catch all for shop to store at the end of my file

Comment: Your rule already matches `cobrand/partner?code=SOMEPARTNERCODE&init=true`. It is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: It is unclear what your question is and what's not working?

Comment: Yes that was unclear. i want the second url(cobrand/partner?code=SOMEPARTNERCODE&init=true) to be ignored and the rules to apply to the first one. So something that forces an ignore if the string is partner?code.... and uses a rule to rewrite the other one

Comment: The only difference between the two seems to be `init=true`. Is this correct?